# Why is 2-methylpropene less in energy than its alkene counterparts?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability, isomers

Other isomers include 1-butene, cis 2-butene, and trans 2-butene. Why would 2-methylpropene be less in energy if there is more steric hindrance?

Answer (score 31):

There are two things we need to understand before we can answer the question.

**1) More highly substituted double bonds are generally more stable than less substituted double bonds.**

This is because the $\ce{sp^3}$ hybridized carbon in the alkyl group is electron donating towards the $\ce{sp^2}$  hybridized carbon in the double bond. Electron density likes to flow from low to high s-character orbitals since the more s-character in an orbital, the lower the energy of the electrons in that orbital.  As the electrons flow from the $\ce{sp^3}$ carbon to the $\ce{sp^2}$ carbon the energy of the electrons (and therefore the energy of the molecule) is lowered.

A "shorthand" way to illustrate this electron flow is by drawing hyperconjugated resonance structures like the following.

[image]

Consequently 2-butene (where we can draw 6 hyperconjugated resonance structures) is more stable than 1-butene (where we can only draw 2 hyperconjugated resonance structures).

**2) Carbanion stability decreases in the order primary > secondary > tertiary**

As we've just shown above, alkyl groups are electron releasing.  If we have a negative charge on a carbon (a carbanion), the last thing we want is to have more alkyl groups attached to that carbon releasing more electron density onto an already negative carbon atom.

**Now we can return to your question** and try to understand why 2-methylpropene is more stable than *trans*-2-butene.   Carbon-hydrogen hyperconjugation is at the center of the answer.  Let's compare some of the hyperconjugated resonance structures that can be drawn for these two molecules.

[image]

Remembering that **a)** more highly substituted double bonds are more stable **and b)** that primary carbanions are more stable than secondary carbanions, we can compare hyperconjugated resonance structures A and B. Resonance structure A contains a disubstituted double (more stable) and a primary carbanion (more stable), while resonance structure B contains a monosubstituted double bond (less stable) and a secondary carbanion (less stable). Therefore, resonance structure A should be more stable than resonance structure B.  Since resonance structure A is more stable than resonance structure B, **2-methylpropene will be more stable than trans-2-butene.**

Finally, we note that *cis*-2-butene is less stable that *trans*-2-butene for steric reasons.  This allows us to place these $\ce{C_4}$ isomers in the following order of stability:

**2-methylpropene is more stable than *trans*-2-butene which is more stable than *cis*-2-butene, which is more stable than 1-butene.** If we examine the heats of combustion for these isomers, we see that our order of stability is confirmed.

[image]

[image source](http://quimicaorganica.webcindario.com/Eliminacion1.pdf)

Comment: Why do you say that a primary carbanion is more stable than a secondary carbanion?

Comment: @Cyclopropane As **Point 2** above notes, alkyl groups are electron releasing, hence attaching them to a carbanion (a carbon already bearing a negative charge) further destabilizes the ion; 3 alkyl groups more than 2, more than 1.