# Stability of dialkyl substituted alkenes

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability

The stability order of alkyl substituted alkenes with respect to heat of hydrogenation was given as

$$\ce{R_2C=CH2} > \ce{RHC=CHR}~(\textit{trans}) > \ce{RHC=CHR}~(\textit{cis}).$$

While I understand that *trans* alkene is generally more stable than *cis*, I don't understand why $\ce{R_2C=CH2}$ is the most stable. Shouldn't there be repulsion between the bulky alkyl groups which leads to decrease in stability?

Comment: See "[Why is 2-methylpropene less in energy than its alkene counterparts?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27346/why-is-2-methylpropene-less-in-energy-than-its-alkene-counterparts)".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following is an image of [hyperconjugative effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperconjugation). We can see a $\ce{\sigma}$-orbital delocalising electron pair with an empty $\ce{\pi^\ast}$-orbital.

[image: hyperconjugation movement]

The explanation to your problem can be given by deciding whether the effect is "centralized" or "decentralized". Let me explain it by an example.

> **A quick scene**:
>
> Suppose, you and your friend is sitting across a boat ($\ce{C_{you}=C_{friend}}$) in the middle of a river, and both of you have to reach on either bank soon (a process similar to delocalization, probably). Assume the methyl groups to be oars you need to move across the river.

In $\ce{R2C_{you}=C_{friend}H2}$, both the oars are with *you*. So, only you can row the boat and hence both of you can reach to the bank soon. Technically, the $\ce{\beta-H}$'s are at *one* carbon, so the effect can happen only on it, hence "centralized" and super-fast.

But, in $\ce{RHC_{you}=C_{friend}HR}$, both of you have *the oars*. So, both of you can row the boat and therefore both of you will reach to either bank a *bit later*. Technically, the $\ce{\beta-H}$'s are distributed equally among the carbons, so the effect can happen on either side, hence "decentralized" and not as fast as in the previous case.

As per your concern on steric factors, you may know that "alkyl" is referred to a straight hydrocarbon chain, and it isn't as bulky as to create "steric hindrance".

I guess that makes some sense :)

---

**EDIT:** The above stuffs explains how is first isomer the most stable. I'd previously said that "steric effects" doesn't matter, but in case of *cis* and *trans* isomers, it matters and it's the only thing that differentiate them (along with polarity). Due to this, *cis* isomer is least stable among the three.

Reference table of $\ce{\Delta H^°_f}$: [http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/thermo/heats-formation.html#Alkenes](http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/%7Echem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/thermo/heats-formation.html#Alkenes) (in #C = 4)

Comment: Interesting analogy. I'm wondering whether it was a reflection of the [wolf, goat and cabbage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf,_goat_and_cabbage_problem):)

Comment: Is this a way of saying that in the trans case, the C-H bonds are effectively competing over hyperconjugation, but not in the case with 2 alkyl groups on the same side?

Comment: @Jabbamanga: Not exactly, but it's very similar. Actually, it is a random phenomenon. The orientation of sigma orbital at time of effect decides which C drives the effect.

Comment: @andselisk: ...or the fox, chicken and grain. ;)

Comment: Could you please add thermodynamic considerations of stability. While the analogy is great I would appreciate a more rigorous answer.

Comment: @trinitrotoluene: added some more points + reference